# Using a cursor with a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I need a cursor for the below query so I can loop through to fetch/update/insert some other data. Can somebody help me with this?

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @TODATE DATETIME
SELECT @FROMDATE = Getdate()
SELECT @TODATE = Getdate() + 7

;WITH DATEINFO(DATES)
     AS (SELECT @FROMDATE
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATES + 1
         FROM   DATEINFO
         WHERE  DATES < @TODATE)
SELECT *
FROM   DATEINFO
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I tried so many ways, but didn't find any that worked.

I'm Using

```
declare @adate datetime
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME 
DECLARE @TODATE DATETIME 
select @FROMDATE=getdate()
select @TODATE =getdate()+7

declare @weekdates cursor for
WITH DATEINFO(DATES) AS (SELECT @FROMDATE UNION ALL SELECT DATES + 1 FROM DATEINFO WHERE DATES < @TODATE) 
SELECT * FROM DATEINFO OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

open @weekdates
fetch next from @weekdates into @adate
while @@fetch_status=0
begin
print 'success'
fetch next from @weekdates into @adate
end
close @weekdates
deallocate @weekdates
```

Still I'm getting errors

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just put it in before the common table expression:

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME 
DECLARE @TODATE DATETIME 
select @FROMDATE=getdate()
select @TODATE =getdate()+7

declare boris cursor for

WITH DATEINFO(DATES)
     AS (SELECT @FROMDATE
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATES + 1
         FROM   DATEINFO
         WHERE  DATES < @TODATE)
SELECT *
FROM   DATEINFO
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

(However, insert usual cautions about cursors almost always being the wrong tool for the job. If you can find a way to do the whole operation in a set based manner, it's usually preferable, and likely to perform better (or at least be more amenable to performance tuning))

Comment: Dare I ask why you called your cursor `boris`? :-)

Comment: @Bridge - sorry, force of habit. I can *never* seem to come up with a decent name for cursors - they're either a) trivial to understand by reading the trivial select statement, or b) so complex to understand that you'll bust the limits of `sysname` in trying to describe them. So they tend to be named `boris` in my code

Comment: @user1776417 What error did it throw? Did you exactly copy and paste? Did you remember to get rid of the semi-colon? Remember to close & deallocate `boris` when you're done.

Comment: @user1776417 - as Bridge says, make sure you remove the `;` before `WITH`. The above code does work (I tested it, with the addition of  `open` and `fetch` statements)

Comment: @Bridge I removed the semicolon. also closed & deallocate the boris when done. But, its throwing an error while compiling only. 
Errors are
1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.
2. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @user1776417 Damien's code compiles fine on my SQL Server 2008 machine. Can you please edit the question to include the code you're currently trying that doesn't work?

Comment: @Bridge I have added the the code which I'm using. Look into it.

Comment: @user1776417 - the fact that you're not aware that cursor variables don't contain an `@` would suggest that you're quite new to SQL Server and/or cursors. I'd re-emphasise what I said below my solution - cursors are rarely, if ever, the correct tool for the job. In SQL, it's far more frequent that we write a query that applies to the entire set of rows.

Comment: +1 - I'd suggest to @user1776417 that you post a new question with what you wouldd actually like to achieve, so we can suggest better ways of doing it.

Comment: Cursor variables can begin with `@` in which case they are automatically closed and deallocated when they go out of scope.

Comment: (Change the declaration to `DECLARE @boris CURSOR;SET @boris = CURSOR FOR ...` for this)

Answer (score 25):

It is fine to use `@` in a cursor name but the syntax you are using is wrong.

```
DECLARE @adate DATETIME
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @TODATE DATETIME

SELECT @FROMDATE = getdate()

SELECT @TODATE = getdate() + 7

DECLARE @weekdates CURSOR;

SET @weekdates = CURSOR FOR
WITH DATEINFO(DATES)
     AS (SELECT @FROMDATE
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATES + 1
         FROM   DATEINFO
         WHERE  DATES < @TODATE)
SELECT *
FROM   DATEINFO
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) 

OPEN @weekdates

FETCH next FROM @weekdates INTO @adate

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'success'

      FETCH next FROM @weekdates INTO @adate
  END
```

When declared as a local `@` variable the cursor is automatically closed and deallocated when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: +100 - "When declared as a local @ variable the cursor is automatically closed and deallocated when the variable goes out of scope." - New to me even as a long time MS SQL developer - thank you!

Comment: 'declared as a local @' explanation is really usefull